# Assert equal in xunit and exclude a field

Tags: c#, xunit

i have a test where i will be comparing two objects.

i am open to know whats the best way to do it.

i have created something for which i have an issue that needs help.

1. following code has an object property that needs to be present
2. i would like to assert that all fields to be present except the id property.
3. i feel like the last 5 statements feel inappropriate, if there is a clearer way of doing it, i would like to know.

```
    [Fact]
    public void CreateTransaction_AddFirstTransaction_ShouldUpdateTransactionJson()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockFileSystem = new MockFileSystem();
        var buyCrypto = new BuyCrypto(mockFileSystem);
        var bitcoin = new Currency()
        {
            name = "bitcoin",
            code = "btc",
            price = 10
        };
        
        // Act
        buyCrypto.CreateTransaction(true, bitcoin, 10);

        //Assert 
        var result = JsonSerializer
            .Deserialize<List<Transaction>>(mockFileSystem.GetFile(TransactionJson).TextContents);

        Assert.Equal("bitcoin", result[0].currency);
        Assert.Equal(DateTime.Now.ToString(), result[0].dateTime);
        Assert.Equal("TestName", result[0].name);
        Assert.Equal(10, result[0].quantity);
        Assert.Equal(100, result[0].total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I love using Fluent Assertions for these kinds of tests ([docs](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#selecting-members)). You could do something like this:

```cs
// Arrange
// ... other stuff
var expectedTransaction = new Transaction { 
    currency = "bitcoin", 
    dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
    name = "TestName",
    quantity = 10,
    total = 100 };

// Act
// ...

// Assert
result[0].Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedTransaction, options => options.Excluding(t => t.Id));
```